# ERROR in installing package and RccpArmadillo dependency on Mac

Tags: r, rcpparmadillo

I am having issues in installing a package from a .tar.gz repository.
When I try to install it, I get the following error:

`ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package ‘xxx'`

I looked online for solutions trying to install RccpArmadillo first but there's a lot of confusion and I am stuck in the process.

I first simply tried

```
install.packages("RccpArmadillo")
```

But I got this strange message

```
Warning in install.packages : package ‘RccpArmadillo’ is not available for this version of R
```

Online, I found suggestions to type in the Terminal (outside R) the following code

`curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /`

But still, not working. I get the following error from the Terminal

`curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C / % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100   162  100   162    0     0    522      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   532 Password: tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format`

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on? How can this issue be solved?
Here are some info about the environment via sessionInfo()

`R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.5.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1 `

The version of R that I am using is the last released for M2 silicon Macs and should not be an obsolescence problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is called `RcppArmadillo` not `RccpArmadillo` (cpp, not ccp). It's simply a typo.

```r
install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
```

Comment: Ok, it solved the RcppArmadillo issue but the package installation is still not compiling.
I got new errors
`ld: warning: -single_module is obsolete
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' not found
ld: warning: search path '/opt/gfortran/lib' not found
ld: library 'emutls_w' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Bot clang and gfortran are installed. I checked this via gcc --version

Comment: There is a number of things to do before you can compile R packages on macOS, see https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ and please accept the answer since the issue in the question is solved.